# Add HREF URL to button that is placed on top of jQuery cycle slider for the active slider image

Tags: jquery, slider, cycle

I have a slider that I've added controls on top of the slider, the normal next & previous ::: Additionally I want to add a button that when clicked on it will open the image in full view (lightbox) ::: My code below does populate the button's href but it seems to be out of sync with the current image being displayed ::: I don't have enough knowledge of jQuery to get to the bottom of this ::: I will Appreciate any assistance :::

```
$('.portfolio-slider').hover(function() { $('.portfolio-controls').fadeIn(); }, function() { $('.portfolio-controls').fadeOut(); });

$('.portfolio-slider .slides').cycle({
timeout: 2000, 
fx: 'fade',
prev : '.prev-slide', 
next : '.next-slide', 
pause: 1,
after: onAfter
});

function onAfter(currSlideElement) {
$('#full-size-button').attr('href', $('a', currSlideElement).attr('href'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have the button that opens the large version of the image grab the current image when it is clicked, rather than with a function that runs after transition:

```
<a id="full-size-button">View Bigger Image</a>

$('#full-size-button').live('click', function() {
    $('#full-size-button').attr('href', $('.portfolio-slider img').is(':visible').attr('href'));
});
```

NOTE: the selector for the visible image may need to be tweaked depending on your HTML structure.

----EDIT----

I just noticed in the JQuery Cycle docs that you may want to use your current code with the callback function for "before" rather than "after":

```
before: transition callback (scope set to element to be shown)
after: transition callback (scope set to element that was shown)
```

If you use the before callback the information will be set to the next slide so your link will open the current image.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: I tried everything you suggested ::: The before function gives me the same result, in that it loads an image href attr, but always the wrong one ::: your first code section did not work at all :::